# Bi-directional text destroying the layout

Tags: php, html, layout, unicode, bidi

In my website there's a header that should display "Welcome *username*.".

```
<span>Welcome <?php echo $username; ?>.</span>
```

The problem is that if the user changes his name to U+202Eusername (where U+202E is the right-to-left override character, or RLO), all the layout breaks.

Instead of displaying "Welcome *emanresu*.", it displays "Welcome .*emanresu*" or ".*emanresu* Welcome" or things like that. I tried adding a U+202C (pop directional formatting or PDF) character after the username, and it worked. Like this:

```
<span>Welcome <?php echo $username; ?>&#x202c;.</span>
```

But, if the username has more than one RLO characters, it breaks again. So what I should do is matching the RLOs characters with the PDFs characters, but I'm not sure of how to do this. And according to the W3C specifications **there's no solution** to this.
Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2):

You might be interested in HTML5 tag `<bdi>`.

Details: http://rishida.net/blog/?p=564

Comment: Interesting, but this of course wouldn't prevent the bug happening in browsers that don't support HTML5 right?

Answer (score 1):

Why not search for this character in $username and if it is found change `<span>` to `<span dir="rtl">` . Also replace these characters with blank in $username

Comment: It doesn't work, it still displays it in the wrong way... And replacing it with blank characters would prevent the usage of right-to-left languages which I'm trying to allow, but I don't see any other option really

Comment: When you spot the unicode control character, you specify your span to display rtl, so of course you can remove the control character because you have achieved what it's purpose was..

Comment: Very interesting idea actually, do you have any idea of how to spot it? Like, how to process the, for example, $_POST['username'] to detect if the RLO is there or not? So far I tried using preg_match_all to find any "&#x202e;" (which is the HTML entity for it) in the string and no luck

Comment: Are you using htmlentities to convert $username before displaying it?
If not you would have to use mb_ereg to match the character. But I strongly recommend using htmlentities so you can protect against XSS vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 0):

[Understanding Bidirectional (BIDI) Text in Unicode](http://www.iamcal.com/understanding-bidirectional-text/)

This article being a very interesting general read about bidi issues also has a section named "Filtering User Input" near the end that seems to be talking exactly about the issue you're talking about.

Answer (score 0):

W3C's solution is that you should be filtering out RLO and other characters from the group known as “[Not suitable for use in markup](http://www.w3.org/TR/unicode-xml/)”.

Do this at the same time as filtering out other unwanted control codes like ASCII 0x00–0x1F (potentially including or excluding the newline character) and 0x7F-0x9F. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3197639/bare-minimum-text-sanitation) for background.

(You should also be using `echo htmlspecialchars($username);`. Maybe your usernames can't contain `<` or `&` but that's not a good idea to rely on in your output stage. Get used to calling `htmlspecialchars` on everything that goes out to the page as a matter of course; define a shortcut function for it if necessary.)